# What is the difference between MD and MKDIR batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos, mkdir

Both command creates folders. I [read](http://www.computerhope.com/mdhlp.htm) that MKDIR can create even subfolders.

- Is that only difference?
- Why there are two commands doing the same?
- Which one should I use?

Comment: Both are same. One (md) is shortcut.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just aliases of the same command.Here are the help messages:

```
C:\>md /?
Creates a directory.

MKDIR [drive:]path
MD [drive:]path
```

and

```
C:\>mkdir /?
Creates a directory.

MKDIR [drive:]path
MD [drive:]path

If Command Extensions are enabled MKDIR changes as follows:

MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.
For example, assume \a does not exist then:

    mkdir \a\b\c\d

is the same as:

    mkdir \a
    chdir \a
    mkdir b
    chdir b
    mkdir c
    chdir c
    mkdir d

which is what you would have to type if extensions were disabled.
```

Answer (score 33):

In addition to @npocmaka's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32370298/5047996), I want to provide a list of all such aliases, just for reference:

```
cd   =  chdir
md   =  mkdir
rd   =  rmdir
ren  =  rename
del  =  erase
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux/Unix/MacOS, `mkdir` is very similar, but `md` means nothing.  If you want something cross-platform, you should use `mkdir`.

Answer (score 1):

**For Question 01**

Literally, `md` and `mkdir` commands are the same in their functionality. Microsoft Learn web page says this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mkdir

Both md and mkdir are able to create subfolders without using any cd command.

For example;

`mkdir a\b\c` acts the same as `md a\b\c` if b and c directories don't exist inside a directory.
It will create 'a' directory then go inside it and create 'b' directory then go inside it and create 'c' directory. If all of a,b, and c do exist, will print an error.

**For Question 02**

Actually, I have no idea dude!

**For Question 03**

If you are expecting a cross-platform experience, you better use `mkdir` command.